# webassembly.instantiate versus Module

Tags: webassembly

I have a imagePV.c file :

```
unsigned char *imageGrayscale(...) {...} .
```

then i've done : $emcc -o glue.js imagePV.c ....

In a index.html i put :

```
    <script src="glue.js"></script> . 
    <script> 
        var imageGrayscale= Module.cwrap('imageGrayscale',...);
        Module.HEAPU8.set(...);
        imageGrayscale(...);
    </script>
```

All works. So my question is : what is the need of instantiate ? I mean, what is the need of :

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('glue.wasm'), importObject).then(obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func());
```

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Your `Module` already uses `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()` behind the scenes.

**Long answer**: Emscripten (`emcc`) is not only a compiler, but also a whole toolchain infrastructure. When you use the `emcc` command, `emcc` calls `clang` compiler to compile your C code to WASM, links necessary JS code to use in the WASM using [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Module/imports), and *generates [a boilerplate JS code (it's called preamble.js)](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/preamble.js) to instantiate the WASM code for `Module` so that devs don't need to write your own code to write bootstrapping code*.

Look at your `glue.js` code. You can find [a line that uses `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/preamble.js#L1921). Unless you use `emcc` without `-s SIDE_MODULE=1` option, it always generates preamble.js code for you. So normally you don't need to use [`WebAssembly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly) on your own.

Some advanced users don't want this big boilerplate and use WASM in harder way, like using clang without emcc. [Then they need to use `WebAssembly` including `instantiateStreaming()` themselves.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/emscripting-a-c-library#bonus_content_running_something_simple_the_hard_way)